# Is DNS server And Host file Are different?

Tags: dns, iis-7.5, hosting

I am unsure Whether both DNS server and Host file are the same or different.

I Hosted an application in IIS and created A host name as website1.domain.com and tried to browse it and it didn't work.

When searching on net i found that we need to make entry in DNS server or Host file.

As in most of the sites that I saw mentioned DNS server or host file. I am unsure Whether the both are same or they both are different.

Answer (score 4):

A hosts file is used by Operating Systems to manually specify the IP addresses for specific domains/subdomains - think of it as an override.

DNS however is a server - think of it as a registry - that keeps track of records pertaining to domains, such as A records, MX records etc.

For the purposes of a local test site, an entry in your hosts file would be sufficient, however for a live site, a DNS entry relating to the domain you wish to have your site hosted on would be required.

Choosing which to use comes down to a few things. Does the server upon which your hosting the site use its own DNS server, i.e. a DNS server on the same network, which the connections to the server will be using as well? Does the domain name the site uses have its nameserver set to one that is externally available (i.e. 123-reg.co.uk). If either of these cases are true, you could probably use a DNS server.

If not, is the server hosting the site running on the same machine as the client that will be viewing the site? If so, you can probably use a hosts file, pointing your domains to the localhost IP of 127.0.0.1, ensuring the domains match the bindings in IIS.

Comment: So in case  I am hosting a interanet website in IIS with a host name, I would have to make an entry in DNS. Am I right Seidr?

Comment: If your site is using a real domain, and a DNS server that is accessible to the outside world (i.e. 123-reg.co.uk, or your own DNS server), then yes an A record in a DNS server would suffice.

Comment: If you're using an 'imaginary' domain name (i.e. one that does not really exist), then you'd either have to use your own DNS server (which the machine hosting / viewing the site would also need to rely upon), or a hosts file.

Comment: Please note, this question would be better being posted on serverfault, not stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is primarily for programming issues, not for server related issues.

Answer (score 2):

Dns server is a server that will help to resolve dns names. ie when you type google.com in your browser , the name will be passed to the dns server provided by your isp. then it will be resolved to ip address by the dns server and your request will be routed to the google ip address by isp network. host file is different one. if you add www.mydomian.com entry in your host file and map it to an ip address 192.168.0.1 then your computer will check ion your host file when you type www.mydomain.com, whether there is any entry for mydomain.com in your host file, and if exists it will be routed to that ip address. in case if there is dns server and you set that server ip in your hnetwork configuration in your pc, then all the domain name request will be sent to that dns server(if there is no host entry exists)